# Объединение двух unbind в один и обращение к img внутри div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#solo').unbind('onMouseOut');
$('#solo').unbind('onclick');
```

1. Как правильно записать в один `unbind`?
2. `<div id="solo"><img><img><img></div>` - как правильно обратиться ко всем `<img>` в `<div>`, у которого `id=solo`?

Answer (score 1):

1. `$('#solo').unbind('onMouseOut onclick');`.

   - Стоит отметить, что события называются `mouseout` и `click`, поэтому если вы добавляли обработчик события как `.bind('click', function() { ... })`, то должно быть, соответственно, `.unbind('click');`.
   - Также стоит помнить, что начиная с версии 1.7 [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) и [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) являются предпочтительными способами добавления и удаления обработчиков событий.
2. `$('#solo img')` - выбирает все `<img>` внутри элемента с ID `solo`.

Comment: 2) строго говоря сначала выбирает все изображения, а потом выбирает все, которые внутри #solo. Справа налево, но сути это не меняет, да

Comment: @xaja не знал об этом, равно как и не нашел сходу ничего об этом в документации, но другие сайты и тесты подтверждают это, спасибо.